# List of icons and their names in iron-icons

Tags: javascript, polymer, iron-elements

In Polymers, to display icons on our page we can use the following

```
<paper-icon-button icon="delete"></paper-icon-button>
```

The icon comes from `iron-icons`.

Now, in example, I am using `delete` icon to show `trash-bin` icon.

Is there is any documentation where I can see the icons list and their names used?

for example:

`Trash bin = 'delete'`

I went through the below link, but couldn't found out what I was looking for https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-icons

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a "Demo" link on the left.
Here is a direct link to it:

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-icons/demo/demo/index.html

Comment: The answer from @Ofisora below is good to keep in mind.
Although all icons can be found in the polymer docs. It is wise to generate a own icon set as this is way more efficient.

Comment: Here's a direct link to iframe with demos, can be printed nicely to PDF as cheatsheet: https://npm-demos.appspot.com/@polymer/iron-icons@3.0.1/demo/index.html

Answer (score 9):

There is a searchable list of iron-icons now available at this URL:

[Searchable Iron Icons List](http://www.twelvetone.tv/iron-icons-search/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

It will load an entire icon set even if you only use one of its icons in your application. You can generate your own Iconset from the list provided [here](https://poly-icon.appspot.com/) and use only the icons your application needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is for you. A demo page with all actual iron-icons set: https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/iron-icons/demo/index.html